# Load a binary asset file into Chrome App

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to make a Chrome app that will have some animated objects in it.

I can load textures by using: `new Image()` and then setting the image's src property to the name of a file in my app's root directory. (This will load the texture)

Is it possible to do a similar thing for binary files that contain my proprietary animation data?  I've looked and looked but I don't seem to find anything that lets me load a binary file that has NOT been picked by the user or dragged and dropped by the user.

If this is something that is not allowed, (presumably for security issues) anyone got any clever workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For files inside the app's package, it should be as simple as loading the file with [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

Use the fully-qualified URL to be on the safe side, obtained with [`chrome.runtime.getURL(pathRelativeToRoot)`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-getURL)

Comment: _No code in comments!_ It's absolutely unreadable unless very, very short and formatted with \`'s

Comment: @ChipBurwell If you have solution code that you want to share, post it as another answer, it's totally appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This was what worked for me:

```
function reqError() {
    console.log("Got an error");
}

function reqListener() {
    var buffer = this.response;
    console.log("Load complete! Length = ", buffer.byteLength);
}

function LoadBinaryFile(fileName) {
    var path = chrome.runtime.getURL(fileName);

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onload = reqListener;
    oReq.onerror = reqError;
    oReq.open("GET", path, true);
    oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    oReq.send();
}
```